# Masked input TextField not showing

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, masking

I have an empty movie clip(say A) on a layer and then I have masked it with a display object(say a rectangle). Now I have an movie clip(say B) containing a input text field and I am adding this movie clip(B) dynamically in movie Clip(A).

When I compile it, the input text field is taking input for sure, cz I have applied some traces on change event of that field.

But the characters inside the field are not showing up.

I have also embed the character after someone's suggestion, but after that the field is not even getting input.

Hope this clears now.

Comment: Please try to clarify. What you say looks like nonsense :S If you can post your FLA that might help.

Comment: which part needs clarification?? and how can i post my fla here??:)

Comment: What do you mean by "embed the text field statically and dynamically"? You need to host it somewhere (dropbox maybe), and post the link.

Comment: you are masking a textfield with some displayobject, or you're using a textfield as a mask?

Comment: @JonatanHedborg... there is a character embedding option in flash.. i have done throuhg it. and called it statically. also i have written in code textFiels.embedFonts = true

Comment: @www0z0k..Actually I am masking an empty movie clip with a display object on time line and than adding input text field in that particular movie clip

Comment: do you have more than one frame? is the masking object present at the frame where you add text? did you try to draw anything on the parent clip of the textfield to check if it'll be visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the mask at runtime instead of doing it in the timeline.

```
myClip.mask = myMask;
```

http://www.fayazmiraz.com/masking-test-input-fields-in-flash/

http://www.fayazmiraz.com/masking-test-input-fields-in-flash-example/

When having these kind of problems it is always nice to draw debug graphics in the same `MovieClip` so you know that the mask works. This way you can focus on the real problem, in this case the `TextField`.